# Informtica administrator connection error

Tags: informatica

Cannot connect to informtica administrator in the browser
I used chrome.
I put localhost:8443/administrator but it says that it refuses to connect.

Comment: anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons. Most common ones are - 
1. check internet, check if informatica is up and running well. 
2. check tomcat server in informatica. check tomcat log, catalina out logs to see if they are having log in entries.
3. Most Imp - check if that port is open/not occupied by other program. use some unusual port# like 65002 to avoid this issue